# Change marker icon during runtime

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to change Google Maps Android API v2 marker's icon during runtime without removing/re-adding the marker I want to change its icon? Can I apply transformations to it (like rotation)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yap. if that icon is made by your own and placed in **res/drawable**folder in your project, you can animate it. For the animation, refer to [the Deve Guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/animation/index.html).

Comment: Marker has a new function added as of rev.7 of API v2. See [Marker.setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setIcon%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor%29).

Comment: @MaciejGórski hi, can you tell me how to update Google map api to rev.7. I tried to use the function but my project do not compile.

Comment: @GingerJim I just updated "Google Play Services" item in SDK Manager and imported , compiled  and then added to main project , it worked for me , able to change marker icon in runtime now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't change the marker at runtime, neither apply rotation to it.

You can use a workaround though - I'm working on a BlinkingMarker class where I have to adjust the opacity of the marker image at runtime.

The only solution right now is to create Bitmaps with different rotation and then add/remove them periodically. The problem with this solution is that adding/removing markers takes a lot of memory allocation so it results in constant garbage collection. A better and smoother workaround is to create all your images up-front and add all of them to the map at once. After that you can use the `Marker.setVisible(boolean)` function to display the one that you currently need.

Caution: measure your bitmaps before you do this, because adding a lot of big bitmaps can cause your app's memory size to grow very big.

You can look at my workaround here:
https://github.com/balazsbalazs/blinking-marker-mapsv2

This is marker which is blinking (changes the opacity of the bitmap) but on the same lines you can apply any kind of transformation.

Answer (score 23):

I am able to change marker icons in runtime easily after updated to `Google Play Services Rev 7` ,  now

> Marker.setIcon (BitmapDescriptor icon)

is availble , previously I did remove and add marker to change color of it.

Comment: What if i have multiple pin and change the color of the pin selected and non selected should be default one? Thank you

Comment: @dhiku , sorry for late response, i am not sure about requirement , you will get market reference when clicked on marker or marker info window , so you can change the icon , you can also maintain HashMap of Markers and process it if you have different requirement.

FYI        BitmapDescriptor green = BitmapDescriptorFactory       .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_green);

        BitmapDescriptor blue = BitmapDescriptorFactory         .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_gray);
        marker.setIcon(selected ? green : blue);

Comment: @dhiku , now i got your requirement , I think you need to maintain a Marker Collection i.e Set

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) are very clear on this issue --

> ```
> Icon
>     A bitmap that's displayed in place of the default marker image. You can't change the icon once you've created the marker.
> ```

If you want to appearance of changing the marker, you have some options.  One is, as you note, to delete the marker and add another one.  The other is to place multiple markers at the same location and toggle which one is visible at any given time.

> Can I apply transformations to it (like rotation)?

You can apply any transformation you like to the image **before** using it to create the marker.

Comment: I just come across this post, is this answer outdated? Because I find that I can change the icon with `setIcon()`

Answer (score 3):

In the [September 2013 Google Maps Android API v2 release](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#september_2013), there is now a new [`setRotation()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setRotation(float)) method for markers, along with a new [`setFlat()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setFlat(boolean)) method.

Here's Google's description of the new features:

> **Give your markers a sense of direction**
>
> We’ve added a marker rotation property, to allow you to rotate a marker around it’s anchor point. The new flat property allows you make the marker lie flat on the map surface, rather than popping out to face the camera. These two new properties are especially useful for indicating compass directions when the map is rotated or tilted.

Here's [an article](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/full-screen-maps-and-new-marker.html) describing the new features.

Answer (score 2):

To change the selected marker icon in the run-time, just add

```
      @Override
      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

       Marker.setIcon (BitmapDescriptor icon);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Only tested for Android**

To change the icon of the marker at runtime I had changed the icon variable from **final** to **non-final** by removing the "final" key in Line 186:

```
final BitmapDescriptor icon;

BitmapDescriptor icon;
```

And change the Marker Constructor from "const" to "non-const" in Line 136:

```
const Marker({

Marker({
```

To make changes in a package you have to follow [this instructions](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-modify-an-existing-pub-package-to-use-in-your-flutter-project-4e909452ee66).

With the google_maps_flutter repo you will get a error like "Could not find pubspec.yaml".
Thats because the google_maps_flutter package is placed in a subdirectory of the repository.

To get the right dependencies you have to add the specific path of the package in your pubspec.yaml:

```
 dependencies:
  # google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/[username]/plugins.git
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/
```

Then you able to change the icon by directly set it on the marker.
I do it by using the "OnTap" Method.

```
Marker marker = Marker(
  icon: firstIcon,
  markerId: MarkerId(id),
  position: position,
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
    title: name,
    snippet: address,
  ),
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _markers[name]?.icon = secondIcon;
    });
  }
);
```

The whole Marker class:

```
@immutable
class Marker implements MapsObject {
  /// Creates a set of marker configuration options.
  ///
  /// Default marker options.
  ///
  /// Specifies a marker that
  /// * is fully opaque; [alpha] is 1.0
  /// * uses icon bottom center to indicate map position; [anchor] is (0.5, 1.0)
  /// * has default tap handling; [consumeTapEvents] is false
  /// * is stationary; [draggable] is false
  /// * is drawn against the screen, not the map; [flat] is false
  /// * has a default icon; [icon] is `BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker`
  /// * anchors the info window at top center; [infoWindowAnchor] is (0.5, 0.0)
  /// * has no info window text; [infoWindowText] is `InfoWindowText.noText`
  /// * is positioned at 0, 0; [position] is `LatLng(0.0, 0.0)`
  /// * has an axis-aligned icon; [rotation] is 0.0
  /// * is visible; [visible] is true
  /// * is placed at the base of the drawing order; [zIndex] is 0.0
  /// * reports [onTap] events
  /// * reports [onDragEnd] events
  Marker({
    required this.markerId,
    this.alpha = 1.0,
    this.anchor = const Offset(0.5, 1.0),
    this.consumeTapEvents = false,
    this.draggable = false,
    this.flat = false,
    this.icon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    this.infoWindow = InfoWindow.noText,
    this.position = const LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
    this.rotation = 0.0,
    this.visible = true,
    this.zIndex = 0.0,
    this.onTap,
    this.onDrag,
    this.onDragStart,
    this.onDragEnd,
  }) : assert(alpha == null || (0.0 <= alpha && alpha <= 1.0));

  /// Uniquely identifies a [Marker].
  final MarkerId markerId;

  @override
  MarkerId get mapsId => markerId;

  /// The opacity of the marker, between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive.
  ///
  /// 0.0 means fully transparent, 1.0 means fully opaque.
  final double alpha;

  /// The icon image point that will be placed at the [position] of the marker.
  ///
  /// The image point is specified in normalized coordinates: An anchor of
  /// (0.0, 0.0) means the top left corner of the image. An anchor
  /// of (1.0, 1.0) means the bottom right corner of the image.
  final Offset anchor;

  /// True if the marker icon consumes tap events. If not, the map will perform
  /// default tap handling by centering the map on the marker and displaying its
  /// info window.
  final bool consumeTapEvents;

  /// True if the marker is draggable by user touch events.
  final bool draggable;

  /// True if the marker is rendered flatly against the surface of the Earth, so
  /// that it will rotate and tilt along with map camera movements.
  final bool flat;

  /// A description of the bitmap used to draw the marker icon.
  BitmapDescriptor icon;

  /// A Google Maps InfoWindow.
  ///
  /// The window is displayed when the marker is tapped.
  final InfoWindow infoWindow;

  /// Geographical location of the marker.
  final LatLng position;

  /// Rotation of the marker image in degrees clockwise from the [anchor] point.
  final double rotation;

  /// True if the marker is visible.
  final bool visible;

  /// The z-index of the marker, used to determine relative drawing order of
  /// map overlays.
  ///
  /// Overlays are drawn in order of z-index, so that lower values means drawn
  /// earlier, and thus appearing to be closer to the surface of the Earth.
  final double zIndex;

  /// Callbacks to receive tap events for markers placed on this map.
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  /// Signature reporting the new [LatLng] at the start of a drag event.
  final ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDragStart;

  /// Signature reporting the new [LatLng] at the end of a drag event.
  final ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDragEnd;

  /// Signature reporting the new [LatLng] during the drag event.
  final ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDrag;

  /// Creates a new [Marker] object whose values are the same as this instance,
  /// unless overwritten by the specified parameters.
  Marker copyWith({
    double? alphaParam,
    Offset? anchorParam,
    bool? consumeTapEventsParam,
    bool? draggableParam,
    bool? flatParam,
    BitmapDescriptor? iconParam,
    InfoWindow? infoWindowParam,
    LatLng? positionParam,
    double? rotationParam,
    bool? visibleParam,
    double? zIndexParam,
    VoidCallback? onTapParam,
    ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDragStartParam,
    ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDragParam,
    ValueChanged<LatLng>? onDragEndParam,
  }) {
    return Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      alpha: alphaParam ?? alpha,
      anchor: anchorParam ?? anchor,
      consumeTapEvents: consumeTapEventsParam ?? consumeTapEvents,
      draggable: draggableParam ?? draggable,
      flat: flatParam ?? flat,
      icon: iconParam ?? icon,
      infoWindow: infoWindowParam ?? infoWindow,
      position: positionParam ?? position,
      rotation: rotationParam ?? rotation,
      visible: visibleParam ?? visible,
      zIndex: zIndexParam ?? zIndex,
      onTap: onTapParam ?? onTap,
      onDragStart: onDragStartParam ?? onDragStart,
      onDrag: onDragParam ?? onDrag,
      onDragEnd: onDragEndParam ?? onDragEnd,
    );
  }

  /// Creates a new [Marker] object whose values are the same as this instance.
  Marker clone() => copyWith();

  /// Converts this object to something serializable in JSON.
  Object toJson() {
    final Map<String, Object> json = <String, Object>{};

    void addIfPresent(String fieldName, Object? value) {
      if (value != null) {
        json[fieldName] = value;
      }
    }

    addIfPresent('markerId', markerId.value);
    addIfPresent('alpha', alpha);
    addIfPresent('anchor', _offsetToJson(anchor));
    addIfPresent('consumeTapEvents', consumeTapEvents);
    addIfPresent('draggable', draggable);
    addIfPresent('flat', flat);
    addIfPresent('icon', icon.toJson());
    addIfPresent('infoWindow', infoWindow._toJson());
    addIfPresent('position', position.toJson());
    addIfPresent('rotation', rotation);
    addIfPresent('visible', visible);
    addIfPresent('zIndex', zIndex);
    return json;
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    final Marker typedOther = other as Marker;
    return markerId == typedOther.markerId &&
        alpha == typedOther.alpha &&
        anchor == typedOther.anchor &&
        consumeTapEvents == typedOther.consumeTapEvents &&
        draggable == typedOther.draggable &&
        flat == typedOther.flat &&
        icon == typedOther.icon &&
        infoWindow == typedOther.infoWindow &&
        position == typedOther.position &&
        rotation == typedOther.rotation &&
        visible == typedOther.visible &&
        zIndex == typedOther.zIndex;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => markerId.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Marker{markerId: $markerId, alpha: $alpha, anchor: $anchor, '
        'consumeTapEvents: $consumeTapEvents, draggable: $draggable, flat: $flat, '
        'icon: $icon, infoWindow: $infoWindow, position: $position, rotation: $rotation, '
        'visible: $visible, zIndex: $zIndex, onTap: $onTap, onDragStart: $onDragStart, '
        'onDrag: $onDrag, onDragEnd: $onDragEnd}';
  }
}
```