# how to rotate a marker on map by user's interaction

Tags: android, google-maps

I will put a marker on Google Maps API v2 on Android. I can drag it around by setting draggable to true. Any idea how can I rotate it by finger? ( I need that user sets the rotation - I should save the angle in program)
It is possible to use `onTouchEvent()` by extending view in normal class to handle touch gestures. but in Google Maps API v2 Android we extend Activity.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235336 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449870/

Comment: Non of these links provide any info about user gestures. I want user to be able to rotate the marker by finger